# What's happening to the value of my member?

Tags: c, objective-c, cocoa-touch, chipmunk

There's a joke in there somewhere.

Anyhoot. In the following code, the `setForceVector` method has no actual effect on the value of member it's attempting to change. By checking the log, I can see the function is being called (by another object handling to a `touchEvent`).

I've used NSLog to check that the `forceVectorfromControls` is actually coming across as expected and it is.

If I set the value of `forceVector` in the **init** or **step** methods it works as intended. But for some reason, it does nothing in the `setForceVector` method.

`cpVect` is a C struct, does that have anything to do with it?

http://pastebin.com/m78f3d63e

I'm stumped.

Comment: Don't synthesize forceVector *and* create an accessor for it.

Comment: Drat. Where's my +1 button for comments? :-)

Comment: My bad, i'd already taken that out though, wasn't the problem.

Comment: Is somebody else overwriting your forceVector somewhere? i.e., are you actually setting it in step: so that you never see the change you make when setForceVector: is called?

Comment: not as far as I can tell. I've been over it with a fine tooth comb, checking every mention of force, forceVector and cpv in every file in the project.

Comment: Where are you calling setForceVector: from?

Comment: Another Object (a Layer in Cocos2d parlance). i know the method is being called because I'm Using NSLog(NSStringFromCGPoint(forceVectorFromControls)) to check it in the console.

Comment: is cpVect a CGPoint structure then? What about the debugger? Have you been able to step through it?

Comment: You really shouldn't leave a straight line like that lying around.  Someone will put an eye out.

Comment: Charlie, +100 for finding a family-friendly way to zing the title!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This smells very strongly of having two different objects without realizing it. Try logging self in the methods and see if it's the same GameLayer doing all of this.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't cpVect be a pointer (line 10)?

Comment: apparently not, that throws up an error. I'm told because it's a C Struct.

Answer (score 0):

`@synthesize` will try to produce another accessor method, though I'm not sure what happens when the two conflict. Have you tried not synthesizing the setter? Alternatively, could you set a watchpoint on the variable and see what's changing it for you?

Comment: sorry, yes, I had already commented it out. Not sure how it got into the pastebin code. Will take it out now. 

And it still doesn't work. When I call the method setForceVector and log the value  of forceVector, I get what I'm looking for. But when I log the value inside step, it's {0,0}

Comment: also, according to cocoadevcentral, in the Learn Objective C tutorial, It's OK to use @sysnthesize and declare your own method too. Apparently @synthesize only create accessors if there are non available.